# INNER JOIN: add up amounts with same id

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I´m trying to add up the amounts from a table if the customer id (KUNDENID) is the same.

These are my two tables:

```
+----------+------------+--------+
| KUNDENID | datum      | Betrag |
+----------+------------+--------+
|        2 | 2013-06-05 |  120.5 |
|        1 | 2013-02-05 |  20.95 |
|        3 | 2013-02-05 |  250.3 |
|        3 | 2013-05-13 |    100 |
|        4 | 2013-01-01 |   1500 |
+----------+------------+--------+

+----------+---------+-----------+------------------------------+--------------+-------------+
| KUNDENID | vorname | nachname  | email                        | geburtsdatum | telefon     |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------------------------+--------------+-------------+
|        1 | Homer   | Simpson   | chunkylover53@aol.com        | 1956-05-02   | 555-364     |
|        2 | Doug    | Heffernan | doug.heffernan@hotmail.com   | 1965-02-09   | 555-3684    |
|        3 | Dexter  | Morgan    | dexter.morgan@gmail.com      | 1971-02-01   | 555-3684    |
|        4 | Sheldon | Cooper    | sheldoncooper@gmail.com      | 1981-04-22   | 555-2274648 |
|        5 | Maurice | Moss      | moss@Reynholm-Industries.com | 1972-03-01   | 555-6677    |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------------------------+--------------+-------------+
```

I tried this INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT k.KUNDENID, vorname, nachname, SUM(Betrag) FROM kunde k INNER JOIN verkauf v ON k.KUNDENID = v.KUNDENID GROUP BY k.KUNDENID;
```

Output:

```
+----------+---------+-----------+------------------+
| KUNDENID | vorname | nachname  | SUM(Betrag)      |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------------+
|        1 | Homer   | Simpson   | 20.9500007629395 |
|        2 | Doug    | Heffernan |            120.5 |
|        3 | Dexter  | Morgan    | 350.300003051758 |
|        4 | Sheldon | Cooper    |             1500 |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------------+
```

So I know the JOIN is correct but how can I show the customer who didn't buy anything in the same JOIN?

My desired Output:

```
+----------+---------+-----------+------------------+
| KUNDENID | vorname | nachname  | SUM(Betrag)      |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------------+
|        1 | Homer   | Simpson   | 20.9500007629395 |
|        2 | Doug    | Heffernan |            120.5 |
|        3 | Dexter  | Morgan    | 350.300003051758 |
|        4 | Sheldon | Cooper    |             1500 |
|        5 | Maurice | Moss      |                0 |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------------+
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT k.KUNDENID, vorname, nachname, IFNULL(SUM(Betrag), 0) AS gesamt
    FROM kunde k
    LEFT JOIN verkauf v ON k.KUNDENID = v.KUNDENID
    GROUP BY k.KUNDENID;
```

Here's [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join)'s basic explanation. They show an example as well.

> The result of a left outer join (or simply left join) for tables A and
>   B always contains all records of the "left" table (A), even if the
>   join-condition does not find any matching record in the "right" table
>   (B). This means that if the ON clause matches 0 (zero) records in B
>   (for a given record in A), the join will still return a row in the
>   result (for that record)—but with NULL in each column from B. A left
>   outer join returns all the values from an inner join plus all values
>   in the left table that do not match to the right table.

Comment: Thanks, works great! And the explanation helped alot!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use Left outer join in place of Inner Join Like :

```
SELECT k.KUNDENID, vorname, nachname, SUM(Betrag) AS Betrag  
FROM kunde k LEFT OUTER JOIN verkauf v 
       ON k.KUNDENID = v.KUNDENID GROUP BY k.KUNDENID;
```

Answer (score 1):

i dont know where is the `kunde table` and `verkauf table` but incase the query is error or wrong jsut switch the name of the tables

```
SELECT a.KUNDENID,IFNULL(SUM(b.betrag),0) AS sum , a.nachname FROM kunde a
LEFT JOIN verkauf b ON b.KUNDENID = a.KUNDENID
GROUP BY b.KUNDENID
ORDER BY a.KUNDENID
```

Comment: Thanks! The IFNULL was the thing I was looking for!